# Finding intersections for interstates using Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I found this query, which works for streets:

```
way[highway][name="Mexico Road"];node(w)->.n1;
way[highway][name="Bryan Road"];node(w)->.n2; 
node.n1.n2; 
out meta;
```

I assumed it would work for interstates but when I plug in "I 55" and "I 270" for example, it gives me nothing. The problem appears to be related to exit ramps being their own structures in the data model.

Does anyone know an equivalent that works for interstates or just all roads?

Answer (score 2):

The query in your question looks for the road *name*. "I 55" and "I 270", however, are modeled in OSM using the [`ref`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:ref) tag because they aren't really names. You need to modify the query accordingly:

```
way[highway][ref="I 55"];node(w)->.n1;
way[highway][ref="I 270"];node(w)->.n2; 
node.n1.n2; 
out meta;
```

This won't return any results, though. The on/off ramps (in OSM called [motorway links](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:highway%3Dmotorway_link)) such as [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/21933159) or [this one](https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/18693160) lack a proper `ref` tag. Link roads in OSM usually don't have a `ref` tag, instead they have [`destination:ref`](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Proposed_features/Destination_details) to specify which roads they lead to. Consequently you need to look for both tags. Also, `destination:ref` can contain multiple values separated by semicolon, so you need to look for partial matches using `~` instead of `=`:

```
(way[highway]["ref"="I 55"];way[highway]["destination:ref"~"I 55"];);node(w)->.n1;
(way[highway]["ref"="I 270"];way[highway]["destination:ref"~"I 270"];);node(w)->.n2; 
node.n1.n2; 
out meta;
```

Unfortunately this query runs out of memory. Maybe an Overpass API expert knows how to optimize it so that it will succeed.